# stick left panel to the top on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done sticking the header to the top of the browser when page is scrolled down. I need left panel also to be freezed when page is scrolled down.

Since header is horizontal and full width it is easy to do with position:fixed but if I use the same method to left panel it is not working out.

Is there any way except `position:fixed`?

code is here

```
    //Primary filter and left panel hing
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('.filter-header, .left-panel').offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    $('.filter-header, .left-panel').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            } else {
                    $('.filter-header, .left-panel').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iseXIqEf/35/)**

Comment: why you are avoiding  `position:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to fix the div position is to use the `Fixed`. I would personally recommend to use this property only, and here is the good example with demo, for how to do this:
[Fixed CSS Property](http://www.pixelbind.com/make-a-div-stick-when-you-scroll/)

Please view it for once and let me know, if you still have some concerns

Review the demo [Here](http://www.pixelbind.com/examples/stick-a-div/)

Answer (score 0):

I just added

```
.left-panel {
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

and it seems to work better with that.

Comment: but did u observe tat right panel is occupying the whole horizontal space

Comment: just set .right-panel { margin-left: 200px; } ... 200px or whatever the width of is your left-panel